# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API doesn't return XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, content-type, asp.net-core

How can I have my vnext API to return XML and JSON ?

I thought that using content-type with application/xml would work as it was before.
Note that I tryed with Accept : application/xml too.

But it seems not.

EDIT :

this is my project.json file :

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Xml": "6.0.0-beta4"
  },

  "commands": {
      "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server     Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

this is my startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
{
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureMvc(options =>
        {
            //options.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatter();

            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Xml formatters are not included as part of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package. You need to reference another package called `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Xml` for this.

Example on how you can add the formatters:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.ConfigureMvc(options =>
    {
        // This adds both Input and Output formatters based on DataContractSerializer
        options.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatter();

        // To add XmlSerializer based Input and Output formatters.
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but now, I always get xml

Comment: I've tested with Accept : application/xml and application/json and content-type with both ... and I always get XML

Comment: Could you share how your configuration file looks like?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug with how options are registered. Can you re-order you calls so that you invoke `AddMvc()` first and then the `ConfigureMvc`?

Comment: @Tim: Just FYI...this bug has been fixed now and will be available in next release...i.e you should be able to call `ConfigureMvc` before or after `AddMvc` without any issue.

Comment: Is this any different in RC2?  My `services` doesn't have a method ConfigureMvc.

Answer (score 12):

Updated details following release of .Net Core 1.0.0

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        // Add XML Content Negotiation
        config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
```

project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.0",
```

For more help see Shawn Wildermuths blog post on the subject: [Content Negotiation in ASP.NET Core](https://wildermuth.com/2016/03/16/Content_Negotiation_in_ASP_NET_Core)

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with MVC 1.0.1! There seems to be no information online about this issue.

Comment: I noticed this doesn't work. It is working in another sample project with the exact same configuration and code. I noticed the only difference between the project that is working (i.e. respects accept-header and returns json or xml as specified) and the one that isn't, is that in the one that is working, only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml(`1.0.1) ` is references whereas in the one that isn't working, both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json(1.0.1)` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml(1.0.1)` are referenced, in that order.

Comment: Yeah, *none* of the answers here work any more. It's very frustrating because everything online points to this question, which is now seriously outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the updated answer for MVC6 rc1

Startup.cs (using [MvcXmlMvcBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/DependencyInjection/MvcXmlMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L50-L61))

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();
        mvcBuilder.AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        // or mvcBuilder.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
```

project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
```

Don't forget as ASP.NET 5 was renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0  and so `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` became [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/DependencyInjection/MvcXmlMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L50-L61) i.e.

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" : "1.0.2",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" : "1.0.2",
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced the similar problems, Have to process in one WEB REST API service ,with using ASP .NET MVC Core 1.1.0 ,  two types of XML body requests **DataContractSerializer** and **XmlSerializer**.

So, in my case I need **FromXmlBody** and **XmlResult** with a parameter of the type of the XML serialization. 
Read this thread and think to write a peace of the code with work around, but when I have a look over the GitHub. I found that the  solution has already existed. 
I have checked, it looks like a quality software engineering solution. 
I want to share the links:
Here is new XML extension for Asp.NET Core ver. >=1.1.0 
XmlResult and FromXmlBody Extensions of ASP.NET Core MVC formatters for XML input and output using DataContractSerializer and XmlSerializer.  
https://github.com/Wallsmedia/XmlResult 
nugget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.Extensions 
It works fine for both type of Xml serialize types(DataContractSerializer and XmlSerializer) in one service/controller/method.
Here is the example:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class XmlExtController : Controller
{
    // GET api/[controller]/xml
    [HttpGet("xml")]
    public ActionResult GetXmlObject()
    {
        object obj = new PurchaseOrder();
        return new XmlResult(obj);
    }

    // GET api/[controller]/dcxml
    [HttpGet("dcxml")]
    public ActionResult GetDcXmlObject()
    {
        object obj = new PurchaseOrder();
        return new XmlResult(obj) { XmlSerializerType = XmlSerializerType.DataContractSerializer };
    }

    // POST api/[controller]/xml
    [HttpPost("xml")]
    public void PostXml([FromXmlBody]PurchaseOrder value)
    {
        var x = value;
        x.billTo.street += " 123";
    }

    // POST api/[controller]/dcxml
    [HttpPost("dcxml")]
    public void PostDcXml([FromXmlBody(XmlSerializerType = XmlSerializerType.DataContractSerializer)]PurchaseOrder value)
    {
        var x = value;
        x.billTo.street += "No -10";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for ASP.NET Core 1.1:

Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc(config => {
        config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
        config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });            
}
```

Csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="1.1.3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

MVC 6 RespectBrowserAcceptHeader is false by default. Hence it will bypass the content negotiation. And that's why probably you're getting XML always after enabling the XML formatter.

You can turn the RespectBrowserAcceptHeader to true by adding the following to your startup file:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You Request hastto send the **AcceptHeader** **application/xml**

> Accept: Which media types are acceptable for the response, such as
>   “application/json,” “application/xml,” or a custom media type such as
>   "application/vnd.example+xml

content-type defines what you are sending see also [Difference between Accept and ContentType Header](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-accept-and-content-type-http-headers)

I'm not sure wether the content negiotiation is for xml is activated per default in asp.net 5 webapi

have lookt at this article: [Content Negotiation and Web API for the ASP.NET MVC Developer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574797.aspx)

Comment: I tryed with Accept too, i didn't say that

Comment: Then have you checked wether the xml content negotiation is active ? see link in my post.

Comment: this seems to be on ASP.NET 4.X, I know how to do content negotiation with web api 2, but my problems come with ASP.NET 5 (vnext)

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified in RC2 to just services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }
```