# How can I do a POST in .NET Core 2.2 if the content is XML formatted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am really surprised by this issue because I remember succeeding in it in an earlier .NET Core version. I am working on a .NET Core 2.2 application which now needs to be called by another application (developed externally) which can only post xml....

This is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<object> Post([FromBody] object value)
    {
        return ("Hi", "Hi2");
    }
}
```

The following requests do cause a response with status code 200:

```
POST http://localhost:58774/api/values
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"a":5}
```

which gives me xml as a response and

```
POST http://localhost:58774/api/values
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"a":5}
```

which gives json as a response.

However, this call results in a response with status code 500 (which is exactly my problem):

```
POST http://localhost:58774/api/values
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Accept-Encoding: gzip

<A a="5"/>
```

So now I am in trouble. Xml formatting works which becomes clear if I **Accept** it as an output type. However, if I post it myself as a **Content-Type** and test that, I get a 500. I also tried [this (old) approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950268/1987258) but it does not seem to work in .NET Core 2.2 . What am I doing wrong? How can I post my xml in .net core 2.2?

**An update after a useful remark.** 
The exception causing the 500 is this one:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 11). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not
>   expected.

However, if I add an xmlns (based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)), I still have the 500:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/values
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Accept-Encoding: gzip

<f:table xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>
```

Then the exception message is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
>   (1, 56). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: https://www.w3schools.com/furniture'> was not expected.

Probably, I need to change my xml. How? Even the example from w3cschools does not help me.

Comment: There should be a specific exception behind the 500. What is it?

Comment: There is: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 11). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <A xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but have you tried adding an xml declaration as the first line of the xml? i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?`

Comment: Scratch that - I made a new webapi project and it errors with the xml declaration. I think it could be a bug with the xml serializer, as I copied the xml output directly from the same endpoint, and used it as input....

Comment: What is your expected value for `object value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Content-Type: application/json` with `{"a":5}`, you will receive `{  "a": 5  }` at server side. It received plain text.

For `Content-Type: application/xml` with `<A a="5"/>`, if you prefer receive `<A a="5" />`, you could implement custom `XDocumentInputFormatter` like

```
public class XDocumentInputFormatter : InputFormatter, IInputFormatter, IApiRequestFormatMetadataProvider
{
    public XDocumentInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/xml");
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(XDocument))) return true;
        return base.CanReadType(type);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var xmlDoc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, LoadOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);

        return InputFormatterResult.Success(xmlDoc);
    }
}
```

Register it in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new XDocumentInputFormatter());
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

By default, For `XmlSerializer`, we need to provide `Type type`, an object type would not be able to deserialize.

If the type of `object value` is definted like

```
public class A
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

You could change your method like

```
public ActionResult<object> Post([FromBody] A value)
{
    return new A { a = 1 };//("Hi", "Hi2");
}
```

And with request like

```
<A>
    <a>1</a>
</A>
```

It will fill value with class A object.

Comment: Good answer - this works in my tests, but it does seem strange that it's actually necessary... the default xmlserializer should just work.